# c++ - Monitor mount folder in linux

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

I would like to monitor and detect if a new file is created on a mounted folder in linux using c++.

I understand that inotify can be used only if the folder is local.

Comment: I implemented inotify in my program to monitor the folder. but i was having issue if the folder is mounted from another server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the common remote filesystems support notification.

The only general way to monitor a remote directory is via polling.

Comment: Yup.. seems like that is the only way.. after searching through the web and testing.